# Maven doesn't find org.junit even though it's in the dependencies

Tags: java, maven, junit4

I wanted to add a test to my small project (please note I removed some bits from the code & changed package names, so if there's any error you see regarding this it might be not this ;)):

```
package my.pckg;


import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;


public class SignedRequestCallbackTest {


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testCorrectSignedRequest() {
        assertTrue(false);
    }

}
```

(I also tried to extend from TestCase in order to remove the static import but it didn't help)

After running `mvn test` it shows me an error that it couldn't find org.junit:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Test Server 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ server ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (MacRoman actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ server ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding MacRoman, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 9 source files to /Users/michael/Projects/fbmuc/server/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] ~/code/src/test/java/my/pckg/SignedRequestCallbackTest.java:[4,27] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] ~/code/src/test/java/my/pckg/SignedRequestCallbackTest.java:[6,16] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] ~/code/src/test/java/my/pckg/SignedRequestCallbackTest.java:[7,16] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] ~/code/src/test/java/my/pckg/SignedRequestCallbackTest.java:[8,16] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] ~/code/src/test/java/my/pckg/SignedRequestCallbackTest.java:[14,9] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Before
location: class my.pckgSignedRequestCallbackTest
[ERROR] ~/code/src/test/java/my/pckg/SignedRequestCallbackTest.java:[18,9] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class After
location: class my.pckgSignedRequestCallbackTest
[ERROR] ~/code/src/test/java/my/pckg/SignedRequestCallbackTest.java:[22,9] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Test
location: class my.pckgSignedRequestCallbackTest
[ERROR] ~/code/src/test/java/my/pckg/SignedRequestCallbackTest.java:[24,12] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method assertTrue(boolean)
location: class my.pckgSignedRequestCallbackTest
[INFO] 9 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.161s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Feb 22 18:02:37 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project server: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] ~/code/src/test/java/my/pckg/SignedRequestCallbackTest.java:[4,27] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] ~/code/src/test/java/my/pckg/SignedRequestCallbackTest.java:[4,4] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] ~/code/src/test/java/my/pckg/SignedRequestCallbackTest.java:[6,16] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] ~/code/src/test/java/my/pckg/SignedRequestCallbackTest.java:[7,16] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] ~/code/src/test/java/my/pckg/SignedRequestCallbackTest.java:[8,16] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] ~/code/src/test/java/my/pckg/SignedRequestCallbackTest.java:[14,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class Before
[ERROR] location: class my.pckgSignedRequestCallbackTest
[ERROR] ~/code/src/test/java/my/pckg/SignedRequestCallbackTest.java:[18,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class After
[ERROR] location: class my.pckgSignedRequestCallbackTest
[ERROR] ~/code/src/test/java/my/pckg/SignedRequestCallbackTest.java:[22,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class Test
[ERROR] location: class my.pckgSignedRequestCallbackTest
[ERROR] ~/code/src/test/java/my/pckg/SignedRequestCallbackTest.java:[24,12] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : method assertTrue(boolean)
[ERROR] location: class my.pckgSignedRequestCallbackTest
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TestServer</name>
    <description>Test</description>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Facebook library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.restfb</groupId>
            <artifactId>restfb</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Gson: Java to Json conversion -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Tigase server snapshot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tigase</groupId>
            <artifactId>tigase-server</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>tigase</id>
            <name>Tigase repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.tigase.org</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>tigase-snapshot</id>
            <name>Tigase repository</name>
            <url>http://build.xmpp-test.net/maven/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

mvn dependency:tree:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Test Server 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ server ---
[INFO] my.pckg:server:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.restfb:restfb:jar:1.6.11:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- tigase:tigase-server:jar:5.2.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- tigase:tigase-utils:jar:3.4.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- tigase:tigase-xmltools:jar:3.4.3-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.240s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Feb 22 18:07:55 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

mvn version:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 18:31:09+0100)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_41, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: de_CH, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.8.2", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Please note that I'm not an expert in java nor in maven, just getting started (especially with maven).
From what I've seen from other articles and questions, I should have my tests within `src/test/java` and my "real" code within `src/main/java` - I have done it like this.

Also I removed once the whole ~/.m2/ folder and it still didn't work.

I also did run `mvn test -X` but it didn't help me. If I should post it please tell me so.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You shouldn't override your `<sourceDirectory>` setting in the POM's `<build>` element unless you have a good reason to.  This attribute determines where Maven looks for *non-test* code. The default value for this attribute is `src/main/java`.  The `<testSourceDirectory>` attribute sets the path to *test* code (this defaults to `src/test/java`.  By setting the `<sourceDirectory>` to simply `src`, Maven considers that entire directory to contain main application code.  Since the `src` directory contains `src/test/java`, Maven then tries to compile your test code as part of the main application.

This is significant because when compiling the main application (during the `compile` phase), Maven omits dependencies with `test` scope.  Test code is compiled in a separate phase (the `test-compile` phase) after the main compile.

So since Maven tried to compile your test code as part of the main application, it omitted the `junit` dependency, and they weren't available on the classpath.  The solution here is to simply not specify the `<sourceDirectory>` element in the POM.

Comment: thanks a lot! That was really the last thing I thought of and is completely understandable. I don't even know why it is there like this.. I guess eclipse did it like that as I created the new project and added maven to it.. thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

By default , maven looks at these folders for java and test classes respectively - src/main/java and src/test/java

When the src is specified with the test classes under source and the scope for junit dependency in pom.xml is mentioned as test - org.unit will not be found by maven.

Answer (score 0):

Just putting image to @matts Answer, so its easy for other to correct the problems.

```
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
```

just delete or comment this line present in **pom.xml**

```
<!--  <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory> !-->
```

[image]

For explanation please go through @matt's answer