# Eclipse - org.junit cannot be resolved, even though it's in the Maven dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've decided to write yet another question in this topic, as no solution from other posts worked for me.

My problem is that eclipse is unable to locate `org.junit` package at all, even though it is available in Maven dependencies and all necessary classes can be seen after expanding `junit-4.12.jar`.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Some technical info about the project and the environment:

- Java 9 + eclipse Oxygen.2 (4.7.2)
- Project is split into Jigsaw modules.

Here's what I've already tried:

- Removing scope from both the project's pom.xml and the parent's pom.xml. Parent's POM looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my-group-id</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-artifact-id</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>my-name</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <modules>
        <module>module.1</module>
        <module>module.2</module>
        <module>module.3</module>
        <module>module.4</module>
        <module>module.5</module>
        <module>module.6</module>
        <module>module.7</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

...and subproject's POM looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>my-group-id</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-artifact-id</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>module.4</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-module-4-name</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

As seen on the screenshot, the class is in the correct folder (src/test/java), so it's not a scope problem.

- Using Quick-fix "Add JUnit 4 library to the build path".
- Removing all .marker files from eclipse workspace.
- Closing and reopening all projects in eclipse (multiple times).
- Restarting eclipse (multiple times).
- Cleaning projects in eclipse (multiple times).
- `Maven > Update Project...` launched from eclipse for all projects (multiple times).
- [Possible solution from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15029935/3470545) - I don't have `sourceDirectory` element defined in any of my pom.xml files.
- *Update 24.02.2018*: [Removing everything from .m2 repository and downloading dependencies again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48957067/3470545) - didn't help.

I think it's also worth mentioning, that:

- Running `mvn test` results in:

  ```
  Results :

  Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
  ```
- Launching the test from eclipse results in `java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods`, which is expected, as `@Test` annotation isn't resolved.
- Running `mvn verify` results in `BUILD SUCCESS`.
- Same problem happens, when I try to `import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger`, so it's not a JUnit problem.

Comment: Have you tried Maven > Update Dependencies?

Comment: @JacobB. If you mean checking `Maven > Update Project... > Update dependencies`, then yes, I have tried that. There's no other option - it's automatically checked and disabled :) I have also tried checking `Force Update of Snapshots/Releases`.

Comment: Alright just thought id recommend it

Comment: In my project, someone or something had added JUnit 5 to the Classpath "folder" (Eclipse term) in the Build Path. It should have been in the Modulepath "folder".  So repeated following suggestions to let Eclipse add JUnit 5 were failing until it was moved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem could be related to the thing how non-modular jars are managed in Java 9. The automatic modules are created for every non-modular java application which doesn't have support for Java 9 and their name is created based on the name of the non-modular jar. In order to fix that, could you please add "requires junit" to your module-info.java?

```
requires junit;
```

Comment: It was exactly my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

My workspace projects had the same problem identifying junit and other libraries after upgrading to Eclipse Photon. What worked for me was Maven > Update Project (you can select all open projects that has the issue). My projects were all in Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

Configuration seems fine.

Please check the jar file in your repository `c:\users\bartl\.m2\repository\junit` as this file may be broken. In my case maven uses another repository different from that in the user's home directory so maven was able to compile successfully.

I suggest deleting the whole junit directory in the repository and let eclipse download the files again.

I experience such behavior sometimes when there is a poor internet connection or no internet connection at all.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion. I've closed eclipse, manually removed everything from .m2 repository, opened eclipse again, cleaned all projects and updated them via Maven sub-menu. Dependencies have been downloaded, projects are built, but the issue persists, nothing has changed.

Answer (score -2):

Add the dependency

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

it worked.